# Android animation not animating despite calling start animation on the target button

Tags: android, kotlin, animation

I am trying to fathom why my buttons will not animate as needed. I have this main button `btn_one` and I have `btn_one_background` which is the action I want to animate when `btn_one` is clicked. For some reason when I pass `btn_one_background`  the animation does not start what am I doing wrong.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         setContentView( R.layout.activity_button)

        val btn : ImageButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_one)
        btn.setOnClickListener {

            startAnimation()

        }

    }
    
    private fun startAnimation(){
            val whiteBackAnin =
                    AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(
                            context,
                            R.animator.button_anim
                    ) as AnimatorSet
           whiteBackAnin.setTarget(btn_one_background)
           whiteBackAnin.start()

    }
```

My layout activity button

```
  <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_one"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_circle_red"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button_content_description"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_options"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        tools:visibility="visible" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_one_background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_circle_white"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/btn_one"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/btn_one"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/btn_one"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/btn_one"
        />
```

Animator

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:ordering="sequentially">
    <set android:ordering="together">
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="1"
            android:propertyName="scaleX"
            android:valueTo="0.25"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="1"
            android:propertyName="scaleY"
            android:valueTo="0.25"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </set>


<objectAnimator
        android:duration="1"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:valueType="floatType" />
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="1000"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:valueFrom="1f"
        android:valueTo="1f"
        android:valueType="floatType" />
    </set>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues that I see:

1. You have the visibility of your `ImageView` set to gone - you should set the alpha to 0 instead
2. The `ImageView` doesn't appear to have a size, as it is set to `wrap_content`, but it only has a background - and then your animation shrinks it - and I think it's probably shrinking it from nothing - so you should set some width and height to that component

Comment: I updated the alpha to 0 and gave the imageview the sizes but still does not animate.

Comment: when i made those changes it worked for me - did you remove the visibility attribute from the `ImageView`?

Comment: I am actually thinking since I have a motion layout it might need me to add it there too. It actually worked but now I am having it show in the background not foreground https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65092442/how-to-bring-button-in-foreground-motion-layout